# Apache File not exists - error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, lamp

My Apache log frequently contains message such as "File does not exist". I have a page named 404.shtml and when I try to receive a Invalid page, the contents of 404.shtml are displayed. But at the same time the invalid page url is also written in the logs.

Is is possible avoid such errors within the Apache log, As sometimes the log is flooded with such entries

Comment: Can you post your httpd.conf file and your file structure for your webroot?  It is likely a misconfiguration with your apache concerning your 404 page.

Comment: Try modifying the [error level](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#loglevel) in httpd.conf file.